# Tengo un problema al calcular promedio por cuatrimestre

Tags: php, sql-server, php7, sql-server-2008-r2

Estoy realizando un historial academico, en la base de datos tengo una tabla de calificaciones del alumno y en el siguiente codigo lo que hago es traer por cuatrimestre todas las materias con su respectiva calificacion.

Lo que he tratado de hacer es que por cada cuatrimestre me de el promedio del conjunto de calificaciones y debajo de cada cuatrimestre me muestre la etiqueta con el PROMEDIO CUATRIMESTRAL: y la calificacion, algo así como en la siguiente imagen:

Comment: Saludos. Solo hace la sumatoria de calificaciones y cuantas calificaciones son (en este caso) hasta el 9no. semestre; y lo usas/pones para  `Promedio Cuatrimestral` te falta la operación similar para promediar por cuatrimestre o es que lo usarias para c/cuatrimestre? por que lo dejaste fuera del `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás mostrando el promedio solo al final, necesitas hacerlo cada que cambias de cuatrimestre.

- Inicializa cuatrimestre con un valor por defecto (cero)
- Dentro del `for` analiza si hubo cambio de cuatrimestre

  - Si el valor de `$Cuatrimestre` es diferente de cero, quiere decir que es el primero y solo muestras encabezado
  - Si el valor es diferente de cero, hay que mostrar promedio y luego encabezado

```
         $suma = 0;
         $contador_calificaciones = 0;
         // Inicializar cuatrimestre en cero
         $Cuatrimestre = 0;

        for ($Cuatrimestre = 0;$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);$Cuatrimestre = $row['Cuatrimestre']) {
             
            if($row['Cuatrimestre'] != $Cuatrimestre) {
                // Mostrar solo si ya hay datos
                if($Cuatrimestre != 0) {
                    // Cambió el cuatrimestre, hay que mostrar el promedio
             ?>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            PROMEDIO CUATRIMESTRAL:
            <?php echo round($suma/$contador_calificaciones, 2);?>  
        </td>
        </tr>
             <?php
                } // endif $Cuatrimestre != 0
                // Mostrar encabezado de cuatrimestre
            ?>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th colspan="5">
            <?php
                     // Tenías un if innecesario, comparando la misma variable
                     echo $row['Cuatrimestre']."o. "."CUATRIMESTRE: ";
            ?>
            </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
                // Reiniciar suma y contador
                $suma = 0;
                $contador_calificaciones = 0;
                // Actualizar valor de cuatrimestre
                $Cuatrimestre = $row['Cuatrimestre'];
            } // endif cuatrimestre diferente
             $suma += (int)$row['Calificacion'];
             $contador_calificaciones++;
        ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Nombre'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Creditos'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ElementoCatalogo'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Calificacion'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Cuatrimestre'];?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <?php           
        } // endfor
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda acabo de probar el código si me funciono ya me muestra el promedio en cada cuatrimestre, solamente el ultimo que es 9o. no lo muestra, pienso yo que como ya no hay mas cuatrimestres despues de 9o. ya no esta tomando ningun dato, quizas este equivocada

Comment: Es correcta tu observación, tal vez removiste el `<thead>` después del `for`, que es donde mostrabas el promedio del 9º cuatrimestre. Si la respuesta te fue útil, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Si lo habia removido, lo volvi a colocar y mostro  el promedio del ultimo cuatrimestre, muchas gracias por su ayuda.